# Problem simulating a fixed transconductor with LTSpice

Tags: voltage, simulation, ltspice

I am simulating a fixed transconductor circuit with LTSpice. When I apply \$1\$V for input voltage, (for DC Sweep) the voltage of collector of \$Q_1\$ has good amplitude (\$30\$mV to \$330\$mV) while the voltage of collector of \$Q_2\$ is in range of MV, considering the \$V_i=1\$V which is the max voltage I can apply based on calculations:

$$V_{\text{imax}}=\frac{I_i}{2}R_e$$

In order to solve the problem, I will apply the input voltage same as before, on the base of \$Q_1\$. Then substitute the current sources with MOhm resistors. Now how can I measure \$i_{o1}\$? Cause I need to find the frequency response of output impedance. 
Based on the book, I can calculate \$i_{o1}\$ but I don't know how to simulate the frequency response of output impedance. Would you please help me?[image]

In the upper picture, shows the question and I need to find \$i_{o1}\$[image: measuring \$i_{o1}\$].  [image: Is my solution right?][image: When circuit had problem]

Comment: Try setting the current sources as active loads. (Right-click -> Advanced -> This is an active load)

Comment: And make them not-so-ideal. Add some large resistors in parallel with the current sources. As drawn, there's nowhere for the base currents to go.

Comment: So, should I have the Voltage source only on one base? Same as what I did for the first circuit?

Answer (score 1):

The base of Q2 is tied to ground, so it's switched off. The current source in the upper right corner tries to keep the current up and pushes the collector of Q2 down.

It would help to supply the common point of I3 and I4 with a negative voltage.

**Added**
Doing a simulation myself (Qucs) i had the same problem, the collector went to the max.

Part of the current through I4 comes from the resistor, thus the upper current source has a problem.

I've replaced the two upper current sources with 1 MOhm resistors. (Supply +/- 8V)
The result was 0.27 V for Q1 and 7.84 V for Q2.

Comment: a negative voltage with what range?

Comment: I applied -0.5v but the Vc2 still is in Mv range... :(

Comment: @Behnoosh - it's your circuit. I would take the same voltage as the positive supply. Up to this point there's no difference to a regular differential amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the boundary I outlined in red in this copy of your schematic:

[image]

By Kirchoff's Current Law, the net current through the boundary must be zero. The 4 paths across the top and bottom edges of the boundary are all controlled by current sources, and the net current for these 4 paths is zero. Therefore, the net current for the other two paths must also be zero.

In equations, \$I_{b1} + I_{b2}=0\$, where \$I_{b1}\$ is the base current of Q1 and \$I_{b2}\$ is the base current of Q2.

If \$I_{b1}\$ is positive then \$I_{b2}\$ is negative, and vice versa. But the be or bc junction of a BJT can only produce a reverse current equal to the transistor \$I_s\$, which is typically in the range of femtoamps.

It seems like what's happening in your simulation is that I2 is driving up to unrealistic high voltages in order to try to produce a reverse current through the c-b junction of Q2. Probably the simulation tool has made some approximation like adding gigohm-level resistors from every node to ground and that is allowing it to find a (non-physical) solution.

To get a realistic solution, try replacing the ideal current sources with realistic cicuits like current mirrors or resistors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the accurate explanation. I will replace them with MOhm resistors.
Based on the fig of the question, I also need to find io1. What shold I do?

Comment: @Behnoosh, what is \$i_{o1}\$?

Comment: the output current, coming out from I(collector2) going to I(collector1) (down the I3 and I4). Can be seen in the small white fig of the question (right down corner of the upper image)

Comment: It's 0 because you have no load connected.

Comment: I don't know how to attach a pic in comment, but based on the problem on page 587 of "Analog Integrated Circuit Desing" [David Johns, Ken Martin] the value of io1 is Vi/(2re+Re).  I just don't know how to measure it by simulation.